# How to bevel this impossible looking junction of edges with multiple bevel width?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, edit-mode

I have just started to learn hard surface modelling and I came around a very tricky corner with junction of 3 edges which I have to bevel.

In the following image I want to create two bevel with different widths, red one for side view and green one for front view while maintaining as smooth bevel for the the junction marked in yellow.

[image: Isometric view]

Front and side view for your reference

[image: Front view]
[image: side view]